# How do I step into a particular callable in PDB, when there are several invoked on the same line?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Often when I step through code in PDB, I get to lines like this:

```
foo(bar(), qux())
```

In this case, I'm interested in stepping into `foo()`, but not into `bar()` or `qux()`.

How do you do this in PDB?

If I just issue a `step` command at the prompt, PDB will trace into `bar()`, then `qux()`, and only then into `foo()` - which is a huge inconvenience when `bar()` and `qux()` are long functions.

Comment: You can set `b(reak)` on `foo` which will pass the execution of `bar` and `qux` and stop when entering `foo`. You can also do that as you are about to perform the `foo` step (also can use `tbreak` for that one time). Or you can step into `bar()` and `qux()` and upon entering have it run until `r(eturn)`. Still somewhat inconvenient, but not terribly IMO.

Comment: @OndrejK. this is something I encounter often when tracing through long logic paths. My goal isn't to trace `foo()` specifically, but to continue tracing through the code path that led me to this call, so setting a breakpoint on `foo()` isn't a solution. Setting a breakpoint on it, then executing a `c(ontinue)`, just to skip tracing through `bar()` and `qux()`, is inconvenient as there are many lines with multiple such calls. Stepping into `bar()` and `qux()`, then quickly running through them with `r(eturn)`, is therefore the least inconvenient solution I can see.

Comment: You can use `unt(il)` to reach a specific line of code first. I've made this into an answer with also conditional break... and you can also do conditional `tbreak` for temporary (one time use) break points. I am not sure it's gonna get better much more then that. What `h(elp)` gets you is what you'll need to come by with.

Comment: @OndrejK. thanks! I'm not ure how `until` helps, as it is about line numbers.

Comment: I mean if you knew which specific line with the `foo()` call you wanted to look into. You can go `until`there, and then do the (temporary) `breakpoint` (or `step`/`return`). Essentially, I understand you're asking for a combo command to step over the calls in parameters and step into into the `foo` itself, but I am afraid there is no such animal...

Comment: I'm not sure it will work, as the docs say `until` will "continue execution until a line with a number greater or equal to that is reached". So if `bar()` is defined on a higher line than `foo()`, `until <foo() first line number>` will break on `bar()` too.

Comment: No. I meant to use `until` just to reach the `foo()` call you wanted to look into... then set your breakpoints. If there is something you could test for, conditional break would be much easier to use though.

Comment: I see!  In this case, the question is about reaching the above `foo()` call while tracing through a long logic path that started long before it, so I can't know for sure I'll end up needing to step into `foo()` (or even reaching a call to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is the answer and not just a comment.

When you are about to run the line calling:

```
foo(bar(), qux())
```

Add temporary breakpoint on `foo()` using:

```
tbreak foo
```

And then just:

```
c
```

or `continue`. This will run `bar` and `qux` and stop once reaching `foo` code block.

You could also just use a regular `b(reak)`.

Alternatively, you can `s(tep)` into `bar` and `qux` but use:

```
r
```

or `return`. To just run them up to returning from them. With "only" two functions as parameters, that is likely still relatively bearable inconvenience.

You can also expand on the breakpoint idea by making it conditional, e.g. if you know you only want to debug `foo` after `x` has has been assigned a value of one:

```
b foo, x == 1
```

This way you could run (or `n(ext)`) through your code and have the breakpoint only trigger when the condition is met.